# InterpolationWarning: KPSS test in Python with statsmodels

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

When I run below code, I get specific warning

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import kpss
kpss(np.random.choice(range(-1000,1000),10000))
```

Warning message

```
<stdin>:1: InterpolationWarning: The test statistic is outside of the range of p-values available in the
look-up table. The actual p-value is greater than the p-value returned.
```

Is it possible to ignore only this warning, without impacting the display of any other warning that may arise in other part of a code file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to mute Interpolation warning by importing `warning` module and `InterpolationWarning` from `statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions`:

```
import warnings
from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import InterpolationWarning
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', InterpolationWarning)
```

Now, run:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import kpss
kpss(np.random.choice(range(-1000,1000),10000))
```

Output

```
(0.269901614649574,
 0.1,
 11,
 {'10%': 0.347, '5%': 0.463, '2.5%': 0.574, '1%': 0.739})
```